# Django: How to make many filters on the same related field?

Tags: django

I have a Django model called Format, that has some fields, and another model called DepartmentFormat that looks like this

```
class DepartmentFormat(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    format = models.ForeignKey(Format, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='format_dptfmt')
    status = models.ForeignKey(FormatStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```

In my view to display the formats, I have some filters, like this:

```
class FormatFilter(FilterUserMixin):

    # SOME OTHER FILTERS

    class Meta:
        model = Format
        fields = ("business_type", "rfc", "economic_sector", "cellphone",
       "format_dptfmt__status__status")
```

However, the same Format can have multiple DepartmentFormat objects related to it, because they can have the same Format, but different Department.

For example, this is a possible case:

- A format has two DepartmentFormat objects related to it. One of those has "Ecology department" as its department, and another has "Public works department" as its department.
- There exists a third Department, which has still no DepartmentFormat object related to it.

So this same Format could have zero, one, two or three DepartmentFormat objects related to it, with each of the Department objects that exist.

What I'm after, is having three filters, one for each of the departments. The first one, for instance, could filter only those Formats for which there is a related DepartmentFormat that happens to have "Ecology department", and the status selected in the filter. I can do this properly by adding `format_dptfmt__status__status` to the fields in the Filter, since `format_dptfmt` is the `related_name` I specified.

However, I can only do this once, and I need to do it three times. I can handle the filtering itself by just making `def filter_<field_name>` methods, but I can't do that if I need three filters filtering the exact same field (`format_dptfmt__status__status`). Is there a way to add multiple filters that filter the same field?

I can achieve this by adding `format_dptfmt__status__status` multiple times in the ```fields", and then three identical filters render, but I cannot distinguish them and make filter methods for them, because they are all called the same.

So, either a name identifier for each filter, or another method altogether, is what I'm after, and I don't know how to try it another way.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem if I don't get it very wrong

```
from django.db.models import Q

model.objects.filter(Q(field1='x') | Q(field1='y'))
```

Comment: However, I'd like to display multiple filters in the view, but all refering to the same field. This would work if I could access whatever the user selected in all three filters, i.e., if I had access in the same method to those 'x' and 'y' value, but since all three filters reference the same field, they are called the same, so to speak. It's not the filtering that's the problem, but how to display three filters in the view, when all reference the same field.

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering this way:

```
list_of_options = ['x', 'y', 'z']
model.objects.filter(field__in=list_of_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used:

```
fields = ("business_type", "rfc", "cellphone", "format_dptfmt__status__status_1", "format_dptfmt__status__status_2", "format_dptfmt__status__status_3")
```

And

```
format_dptfmt__status__status_1 = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(empty_label='---Ecología---', label='Ecología', field_name='format_dptfmt__status__status', choices=((1, 'Aceptado'), (2, 'Rechazado')), method='filter_format_dptfmt__status__status_1')
format_dptfmt__status__status_2 = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(empty_label='---Protección civil---', label='Protección civil', field_name='format_dptfmt__status__status', choices=((1, 'Aceptado'), (2, 'Rechazado')), method='filter_format_dptfmt__status__status_2')
format_dptfmt__status__status_3 = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(empty_label='---Obras públicas---', label='Obras públicas', field_name='format_dptfmt__status__status', choices=((1, 'Aceptado'), (2, 'Rechazado')), method='filter_format_dptfmt__status__status_3')
```

And then just filtered by each Department object in the method for each filter. I don't know why Django allowed this, since `format_dptfmt__status__status_1` is not a field for the Format object, but just adding the three filters individually, and just using the same field_name for all of them, seemed to work.